# Magit running git commit takes forever

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I am using Emacs on Mac OS with the package Magit. Everything works fine except when I try to do a commit (shortcut: `c c`). Magit hangs with this message in the bottom bar:  "running git commit".
What is weird is that when I stop the command (Ctrl-g), magit shows me the buffer to write my commit message and everything works fine. I don't know why this happens.

```
with-editor-emacsclient-executable
```

is set to `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/bin/emacsclient`.

and calling `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/bin/emacsclient` filename directly from the console seems to work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you `$` (which is `magit-process-buffer`), you'll see what git is doing in the background

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a common problem when dealing with a large repo or a repo that has been around for a long time. Try cleaning up the repo. You can use these:

```
git remote prune origin
git gc
```

From the official docs:

> `git remote prune origin`
>
> Deletes all stale remote-tracking branches under `name`. These stale 
>   branches have already been removed from the remote repository referenced
>   by `name`, but are still locally available in "remotes/`name`".
>
> `git gc`
>
> Runs a number of housekeeping tasks within the current repository,
>   such as compressing file revisions (to reduce disk space and increase
>   performance) and removing unreachable objects which may have been
>   created from prior invocations of git add.
>
> Users are encouraged to run this task on a regular basis within each
>   repository to maintain good disk space utilization and good operating
>   performance.

Could be an issue with large diffs too:

https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2048

Comment: could you please expand on what that commnand does exactly? This didn't work for me.

Comment: @maroxe, have added the details

Comment: @maroxe, also what worked for me is cleaning up my remotes to reduce the number of branches. Like I said seems to be common for large repos like Linux. See https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2097

Comment: I think here the problem is related to the magit tries to reach the editor and loops for something to happen. If I abort that process then I have access to the commit buffer an I can commit as usual.  Committing from the command line woks fine.

Comment: @maroxe, actually if you press `c` instead of `C-g` it will work just the same

Comment: what do you mean by that? just pressin `c` does nothing for me

Comment: I meant I don't think it is because a process is hanging if it is stuck, I usually press `c` again and I get the commit msg window